# A way to go over the diagonals of an array of size [6][7]

Tags: c, arrays

I'm building in C language, a game called 4-in-a-row or Connect Four, for a fast review of the game you can see here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four

so, I have a 2 dimensional array of size [6][7], and I want to check in diagonal if there are 4 tokens which are "*" or "o" that are defined as a chars which are in a a row. I'm trying to write a function that after each play, it sums up all the possible diagonals and see if the sum is 4 for example, or if we want to check in pairs, if we get three similar pairs then there are 4 equal tokens in a row, so in this case the sum is 3, and so on..

for all I know, there are 12 different different diagonals (every 6 on different direction), how do u suggest me to write this function while being the most effective? and also including all the possibilities with less that 16 lines of code. 
any kind of help would be appreciated!

here is an example of what I did:

```
int CheckDiagonal_1(char matrix[Rows][Columns])
{
    int s_count = 0;
    int o_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 5; j >= 3; j--)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k <= 3; k++)
            {
                if(matrix[j-k][i+k]== matrix[j-k-1][i+k+1]) count ++;
                if(count==4) return count;
            }
            count = 0;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jongware I suppose an array of `42` elements...

Comment: @Jongware I edited. it means 6 lines and 7 columns.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this yourself yet?  Any code to show?

Comment: yeah, but I didn't reach a complete solution, I will try to put something in few minutes..

Comment: Homework attempt without posting any code or making any attempt to solve by oneself.

Answer (score 1):

Diagonals are sequences where

- `i == j + c` for i from (0,height) and c (-width, height)
- or `i == -j + c`.

So if goal to write code that fits into small number of lines - just write loops that go over i {0-6} and check for indexes to fit in range. Something like

```
for (int c= -7; c < 7; c++)
{
  int starsOnDiag = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  { 
     starsOnDiag += !indexesInRange(i, j) ? 0 :
         cell[i, i+c] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
  }
  ... // other diagonal and check for other symbol
 }
```